# How to verify a custom event in a Cypress test?

Tags: angular, typescript, cypress, lit

In my Typescript file I am dispatching a custom event when some information is loaded to the html page.

```
  dispatchEvent() {
    const myCustomEvent = new CustomEvent('myCustomEvent', {
      id: 123,
    });
    this.dispatchEvent(myCustomEvent);
  }
```

I can see that the event is dispatched correctly in console so I think I don't need to dispatch it also from Cypress but maybe I'm wrong. Any ideas how to verify that the custom event is emitted and also has the desired data?

Comment: just add an eventlistener to window. Events bubble.

Comment: tried that, but it doesn't catch it. It works if I dispatch the event again in the Cypress test though

Comment: did you use the [cy.window()](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/window)?

Comment: The second arg to the `CustomEvent` constructor is an options object. You should provide `{bubbles: true, composed: true, detail: {id:123}}`

Answer (score 4):

#### Component tests

There is an example using `change` event here [Angular examples](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/component-testing/angular/examples#Using-createOutputSpy) which uses the `createOutputSpy` helper utility function from `cypress/angular`.

You should just be able to substitute your custom event name

```js
import { createOutputSpy } from 'cypress/angular'

it('tests custom event', () => {
  cy.mount(myComponent, {
    declarations: [...],
    componentProperties: {
      myCustomEvent: createOutputSpy<any>('myCustomEventSpy'),
    },
  })
  ...
  // trigger action here, or none if triggered on mounting

  cy.get('@myCustomEventSpy')
    .should('have.been.called')
    .its('firstCall.args.0')
    .should('deep.equal', { id: 123 })
})
```

---

#### e2e tests

If you are performing e2e tests instead of component tests, an event spy might be configured something like this:

```js
cy.visit('/', {
  onBeforeLoad: (win) => {
    win.addEventListener('myCustomEvent', cy.stub().as('myCustomEventSpy'))
  },
})

...
// trigger action here, or none if triggered on page loading

cy.get('@myCustomEventSpy')
  .should('have.been.called')
  .its('firstCall.args.0')
  .should('deep.equal', { id: 123 })
```

Comment: thank you but I can't mount my Lit element like this. Currently mounting it through the html: 
cy.mount(
  html`<my-lit-element
    .inputId="${inputId}"
  ></my-lit-element>`
)
I'm not able to add the spy here.